# PHP infinite loop. I am not able to see the mistake

Tags: php

I need help understanding where I made a mistake in this loop.

When I check the webhook.log file, I see the following

0123405162734051627340516273405162734560712345670123456701234567012345670

Which obviously variable "i" values are taking those above and the for loop is not ending, which I cannot understand why.

```
for ($i=0; $i < count($chats); $i++)
{    
    $data = [
        chatId => $chats[$i],
        body => $base64img,
        filename => $nombreimg[1],
        caption => $arr["message"]["caption"]
    ];

    $json = json_encode($data);
    $url = 'https://XXXX.chat-api.com/instanceXXXX/sendfile?token=XXXXXXXXXXXXX';

    $options = stream_context_create(['http' => [
        'method'  => 'POST',
        'header'  => 'Content-type: application/json',
        'content' => $json
        ]
    ]);

    $result = file_get_contents($url, false, $options);
    file_put_contents("webhook.log", $i, FILE_APPEND);
    sleep(15);
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: From where do you execute this code? By what is it triggered and called? Also: is this your complete loop-code, or did you remove things from it? If you omitted some code, please include it, certainly any `if` and calls to other functions.

Comment: Do you delete the file after every run? Or the Append is for all of the calls?

Comment: I did not find the error but, Try **foreach**, instead of **for**. It is faster and safer.

Comment: You need to clear the file content before starting the loop, since you are `appending` on the file, this file will keep values from older runs of your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we suppose that your PHP script only contains this code then :
Your log file content suggest that more than one instance of the script use the file at the same time.It is a more plausible explanation of such content than an infinite loop.

Example:
User one run the script in a browser so the loop start and data is added to the file each iteration.But each iteration unfortunately you let the script sleep for a laps so  another instance start or continue to append data too to the same file. This explains the disorder in your log file...More you have different instances of the same script running at the same time, more the entropy of your content will be worse.

However if your script contains more code that you don't post then the content suggest that you misuse the $i variable in nested loop and this could lead to infinite loop and  to this level of entropy in your log file...

Comment: An API was calling my script, but I didnt respond to it, so the API called my script again and it caused the problem. Thanks, your answer helped me a lot

Answer (score 0):

I think you need it to check the $chats array content, validate if $chats have assign elements .

```
  if(sizeof($chats) > 0){
     loop...
  }
```